# Rails bi-directional looped associations doing weird queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have model named **User** and I want to achieve 2 ways friends functionality using model named **Friendship**.

User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  has_many :invited, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend

  has_many :inverse_friendships , :class_name => "Friendship" , :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :invited_by, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user

end
```

Friendship:

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
end
```

I am creating friendships kind of this

```
u1 = User.find(1)
u2 = User.find(2)

u1.friendships.create(friend_id: u2.id)
```

now when in `before_save` of friendship I try to check if user has already received a friend request like

```
self.user.inverse_friendships.where(user_id: self.friend_id)
```

I was expecting it to search Friendship table where user_id = 2 and friend_id = 1, instead its generating this query

> Friendship Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships"
>   WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1 AND "friendships"."friend_id" = $2
>   AND "friendships"."user_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["user_id", 1],
>   ["friend_id", 1], ["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]

and even with only

```
self.user.inverse_friendships
```

I was expecting search on Friendship table where friend_id = 1, its generating query like

> Friendship Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships"
>   WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1 AND "friendships"."friend_id" = $2
>   LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 1], ["friend_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]

**But If I try query directly from console, it works as expected**

Its even working in instance method, only not working in callback
what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it was happening
but changing

```
current_user.friendships.where(friend_id: permitted_params[:friend_id]).first_or_create
```

To

```
current_user.friendships.create(friend_id: permitted_params[:friend_id])
```

it took hours but still don't know exact reason